# Lines in $\Bbb R^2$ inducing lines in the Torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Viewing the torus as $T^{2} = \mathbb{R}^{2} / \mathbb{Z}^{2} $, let $L$ be a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ through the origin. How many path components does $T^{2} \setminus L$ have in terms of the slope of L?

Hint: consider the case where the slope is rational first.

I'm not sure how to solve this. I have read somewhere that the image of $L$ in the torus is dense if and only if the slope is irrational, which seems to make sense, but not entirely sure if this helps solve the question.

Comment: Can you make any further conclusions at all in the case that the slope is rational?

Comment: My suspicion is that it has a single path component, but I'm too sure if I could prove that. Does that seem correct to you?

Comment: Indeed, in fact the image of $L$ is a circle and the complement of that circle is an open annulus.

Comment: Ah yes I see - great thanks! I still struggle to see what happens to the path components in the case that the slope is irrational - do you have any insight on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the slope of $L$ is rational then the image of $L$ in $T^2$ is a circle, and the complement of the image is an open annulus hence is connected.

If the slope of $L$ is irrational then the covering map is injective on $L$, and indeed on every line parallel to $L$. Let's consider all covering translates of $L$:
$$L_{(m,n)} = \{(x+m,y+n) \mid (x,y) \in L, (m,n) \in \mathbb Z^2\}
$$
There's only countably many of these covering translates, and each of them has the same injective image in $T^2$.

What about the uncountably many other lines $L'$ in $\mathbb R^2$ that are parallel to $L$? Well, each of them has countably many covering translates $L'_{(m,n)} = \{(x+m,y+n) \mid (x,y) \in L', (m,n) \in \mathbb Z^2\}$, and each of those translates has the same image in $T^2$. Thus, the uncountable set of lines in $\mathbb R^2$ parallel to $L$ is partitioned into subsets of countably infinite size, each partition element representing lines with the same image in $T^2$, different partition elements representing lines with disjoint image in $T^2$. There are uncountably many partition elements, and hence uncountably many distinct component of $T^2$ minus the image of $L$.

So the upshot is: $T^2$ minus the image of $L$ has either one component (when the slope of $L$ is rational), or an uncountably infinite number of components (when the slope of $L$ is irrational).